# Groupby function on pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

If I index a dataframe on col1 and call groupby on col1, get KeyError.

```
filtered_df = filtered_df.set_index("STNAME")
for group, frame in filtered_df.groupby('STNAME'):
```

KeyError: 'STNAME'

Works fine if I remove the index. But groupby can be on any column right?

Comment: Well it's not a column anymore if it's the index is it?, you can `groupby` on the index `for group, frame in filtered_df.groupby(level='STNAME'):`

Comment: Maybe you thought that the `STNAME` column remained both a column and was placed in the index with `set_index`? If that's the case, notice you have to pass `drop=False` to `set_index` for the column to not be dropped.